# One page website pages moves when browser is resized

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a basic one page website layout, but If I'm on a 'page' that isn't the first and the browser is resized, the page will move up 300px or so. Same thing happens if I maximise the browser. I thought it may have been all the content moving the page, but I've removed everything and it's still doing this. Is there a way for the page to stay where it is until the user scrolls even when the browser is resized?

html:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#one">one</a></li>
        <li><a href="#two">two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#three">three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#four">four</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="one"><p>section one</p></div>
<div id="two"><p>section two</p></div>
<div id="three"><p>section three</p></div>
<div id="four"><p>section four</p></div>
```

css:

```
* {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

html, body {
height: 100%;
margin: auto;
}

#one, #two, #three, #four {
min-height: 100%;
margin: auto;
}

#one {
background-color: #916e80;
}

#two {
background-color: #ffc3a0;
}

#three {
background-color: #a3e0c9;
}

#four {
background-color: #b0b3b6;
}

#nav  {
position: fixed;
right: 0px;
z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: You need to use javascript to achieve what you want. You can use this - http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/

Comment: Which device and browser are you testing on?

Comment: Tested on windows pc Chrome, Firefox, IE, Opera Safari, and Mac Chrome and Safari

Comment: @Luis P. A. If I can help it I don't want to use a template.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is a problem with your code - the "300px-issue" will not be present when a visitor visits the page and clicks through the menu.

When you resize the browser "manually", it does not reflect the way a visitor sees the page.

As a test, click through the menu to show for example "../test.html#two" - copy the address - open a new tab and resize the browser-window to any size - paste the address in the new tab: the "300px-issue" will not be there and only show #two in 100% height.

If you want to the website to be able to change dynamically when resizing the viewport of the browser manually, you should go for CSS mediaquiries.

Comment: Although this is true (at least something is working), I find it quite unprofessional if someone was to change the browser size and the content started moving. 

I also changed the #two to height: 100% but still remains the same. Thank you for your help

Comment: When visiting a website no one changes the browser-size (aka viewport) - this is only done by me and you because we are developers.